# Wi-Fi problem on Asus Laptop

Tags: networking, wireless, power-management

My laptop sometimes loses the Wi-Fi signal. I had basically thought it does because of low battery and changing a power profile, but I understood over time the problem appears when my laptop even is charging.

I had installed Windows near of the Ubuntu, the OS has no such problem.

I attempted to change a file:

```shell
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

[connection]
wifi.powersave=2
```

I tried several other Wi-Fi routers, tried to change the kernel to newer and inclined to think there is the problem somewhere else on Ubuntu.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy.

Kernel: x86_64 Linux 6.2.10-060210-generic

```
$ lspci -knn | egrep 'Eth|Net'
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:304b]
```

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.